# Samsung Portable DVD Writer

Tags: dvd

I am trying to get my Samsung 'Portable DVD Writer SE-208' (TSSTcorp CDDVDW SE-208DB MF00) on my Raspberry pi 2.

It shows up as /dev/sr0, and from lsusb as: Bus 001 Device 015: ID 0e8d:1806 MediaTek Inc. It only has a USB cable (no power cable) I have tried it in the USB ports in both my Raspberry pi unit and the powered USB hub. I have also tried several media players (VLC, juK, KMix, MPlayer). It does not get recognized by the players.

It ***is*** recognized as 'Audio CD' by Dolphin (when I have an audio CD in it) --- ***but***, that's only if I run Dolphin as root. And then I have to right-click a single .wav file and select 'Open With...' and then MPlayer.

I try to mount it similarly to the way that I *successfully* mount all my other USB devices:
sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/usb -o uid=matthew,gid=matthew mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only mount: /dev/sr0: can't read superblock

This is the way I *successfully* mount various thumb/flash drives, and IDE hard drives (old internal hard drives now utilized via IDE/USB adapters), external USB hard drive (Iomega), etc.

Here are some things that I've tried:

```
> sudo adduser matthew optical
adduser: The group `optical' does not exist.


> id
uid=1001(matthew) gid=29(audio) groups=1002(matthew),29(audio),108(lpadmin)


> newgrp cdrom

/home/matthew : [1920]

id
uid=1001(matthew) gid=24(cdrom) groups=1002(matthew),24(cdrom),29(audio),108(lpadmin)

For the following 'mplayer' command - I have tried it as follows:
a) with both the command line version ***AND*** the GUI version
b) with my cdrom group active ***AND*** with the audio group active (in separate shells via 'newgrp')


> mplayer cdda:///media/usb
MPlayer svn r34540 (Raspbian), built with gcc-4.6 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing cdda:///media/usb.
Can't open CDDA device.
Failed to open cdda:///media/usb.


Exiting... (End of file)

/home/matthew : [1922]

ls -lisa /media
total 20
17956865 4 drwxr-xr-x  5 root    root    4096 Oct 11 18:19 .
       2 4 drwxr-xr-x 26 root    root    4096 Sep 23 10:56 ..
17961727 4 drwxr-xr-x  2 matthew matthew 4096 Sep 15 10:44 cdrom
19662493 4 drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 Sep 18 10:21 sdb1
17961692 4 drwxrwxrwx  2 matthew matthew 4096 Aug 29 12:15 usb

/home/matthew : [1923]

!!/usb
ls -lisa /media/usb
total 8
17961692 4 drwxrwxrwx 2 matthew matthew 4096 Aug 29 12:15 .
17956865 4 drwxr-xr-x 5 root    root    4096 Oct 11 18:19 ..

/home/matthew : [1924]

^usb^cdrom
ls -lisa /media/cdrom
total 8
17961727 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 matthew matthew 4096 Sep 15 10:44 .
17956865 4 drwxr-xr-x 5 root    root    4096 Oct 11 18:19 ..

/home/matthew : [1925]

mplayer cdda:///media/cdrom
MPlayer svn r34540 (Raspbian), built with gcc-4.6 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing cdda:///media/cdrom.
Can't open CDDA device.
Failed to open cdda:///media/cdrom.
```

How do I get this thing to work?

TIA, Matt

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, Matt! What type of media do you have in the drive when you try to mount it?

Comment: Phil, Thanks for the reply. Sorry for my late response - I just saw this. To answer your question: I've only tried audio-cd's. I have no intention of attempting to utilize DVDs. Just audio CDs and more importantlly - reading data CDs. Yes, old-school, I know. I'm slowly weaning myself off of CDs!

Answer (score 2):

Audio CDs are **NOT** mountable media. They can only be read by utilities that are able to interpret their data - they don't have a "filesystem". And, as correctly noticed by `mount`, an Audio CD is Read-Only - you can suppress this warning by mounting with the `-r` flag.

As per [this forum thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/creating-an-iso-from-an-audio-cd-with-dd-670913/) "Audio CDs don't contain filesystems. They actually resemble phono tracks, which spiral inward and have gaps to mark the track boundaries.".

The answer to "How do I get *this* to work" hence depends on the exact definition of "*this*":

- If you want to copy tracks, look into tools like `cdrdao` or `brasero`
- To play songs, you could look at tools like amaroK, or the players you've already tried. To overcome the "only if I run it as root" problem, you need to look at your mount privileges - best is to add a line to /etc/fstab and use the "users" flag to allow any user to mount the filesystem - as well as at the mount-point - make sure that directory is rwx for all users and groups (`chmod 777 /mnt/dir` will do the trick).

Comment: a) for now it doesn't need to go in fstab. I can explicity mount it.

Comment: b) For now I just want it to work with commercial audio CDs and nothing more.

Comment: Here is /media.............................. ls -lisa
total 20..............................
17956865 4 drwxr-xr-x  5 root    root    4096 Oct 11 18:19 .
 ..............................2 4 drwxr-xr-x 26 root    root    4096 Sep 23 10:56 ..
17961727 4 drwxrwxrwx  2 matthew matthew 4096 Sep 15 10:44 cdrom..............................
19662493 4 drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 Sep 18 10:21 sdb1..............................
17961692 4 drwxrwxrwx  2 matthew matthew 4096 Aug 29 12:15 usb

Comment: Phil is correct.  The *device* is not the same thing as the media on it. Have [a look here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-mplayer-playing-audio-dvd-cd-using-bash-shell/) WRT using `cddr` with mplayer.  Notice, a `/dev` node, not a mount point.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the link goldilocks.

For future Googlers who are trying to:

```
a) access a USB 'Samsung Portable DVD Writer' from their:
b) Raspbian Linux OS (on their Raspberry PI computer), in order to:
c) Play a commercial audio CD
```

This command will work:

```
mplayer -cdrom-device /dev/sr0 cdda:// -cache 50000 -cache-min 95
```

This works even better:

```
mplayer -cdrom-device /dev/sr0 cdda:// -cache 300000
```

Here's the output (and note that it takes about 15 minutes to fill up cache - but it won't work any other way.....for me at least):

```
> mplayer -cdrom-device /dev/sr0 cdda:// -cache 50000 -cache-min 95
MPlayer svn r34540 (Raspbian), built with gcc-4.6 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing cdda://.
Found audio CD with 14 tracks.
Cache fill:  0.00% (0 bytes)   
Track 1
Cache fill: 95.00% (48637008 bytes)   

rawaudio file format detected.
Cache not responding! [performance issue]
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [pcm] Uncompressed PCM audio decoder
AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 1411.2 kbit/100.00% (ratio: 176400->176400)
Selected audio codec: [pcm] afm: pcm (Uncompressed PCM)
==========================================================================
AO: [pulse] 44100Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
Video: no video
Starting Playback...
A: 217.8 (03:37.7) of 3206.1 (53:26.1)  0.1% 29%
```

And finally, note that there is good information at:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-mplayer-playing-audio-dvd-cd-using-bash-shell/